# Program works in Mac OS, but not in Windows

Tags: c

Please excuse the copy-paste from another site, like this one:

I wrote a program to store data in a table, linked like a linked list (don't know if that's an original idea-- I came up with it myself, but it might not be a new one). It compiles successfully on Windows, but when I run it, it just says,

> "dlt_table.exe has encountered an error and needs to close."

The only time I've had this issue was one time when I tried to dereference a null pointer out of morbid curiosity. Realizing that the system simply may have been returning null pointers from `malloc()`, I tried checking for the error. Still nothing.

Then, I tried it on my Mac. It built without a problem, and, better yet, the algorithms I came up with actually worked! But I'm still puzzled as to why it didn't work with Windows. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h> (Windows only- taking it out for Mac dev)
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*############################################################################*/

/*Node structure-- this is what the table is built off.*/
typedef struct dlt_node {
        int value;
        struct dlt_node *left, *right, *up, *down;
        } dlt_node_t;

/*############################################################################*/

/*Function prototypes-- visible at bottom of file.*/        
dlt_node_t *make_table(void);
int len_table(dlt_node_t *bucket);
int parse_table(dlt_node_t *bucket);

/*############################################################################*/

main()
{
      dlt_node_t *bucket = make_table();

int table_size = len_table(bucket);
      printf("Table size: %i\n", table_size);

parse_table(bucket);

//getch();
      return 0;
      }

/*############################################################################*/

/*Make a table, and return the table's bucket.*/
dlt_node_t *make_table(void)
{
           /*Allocate structures.*/
           dlt_node_t *bucket = (struct dlt_node*) malloc(sizeof(struct dlt_node));
           dlt_node_t *node1 = (struct dlt_node*) malloc(sizeof(struct dlt_node));
           dlt_node_t *node2 = (struct dlt_node*) malloc(sizeof(struct dlt_node));
           dlt_node_t *node3 = (struct dlt_node*) malloc(sizeof(struct dlt_node));

/*Check for NULL's.*/
           if(bucket == NULL || node1 == NULL || node2 == NULL || node3 == NULL){
                     printf("ERR: ENOMEM.\n");
        //             getch();
                     return;
                     }

/*Assign values, then pointers to other members of the table*/
           bucket->value = 1;
           node1->value = 2;
           node2->value = 3;
           node3->value = 4;

bucket->left = NULL;
           bucket->right = node1;
           bucket->up = NULL;
           bucket->down = node2;

node1->left = bucket;
           node1->right = NULL;
           node1->up = NULL;
           node1->down = node3;

node2->left = NULL;
           node2->right = node3;
           node2->up = bucket;
           node2->down = NULL;

node3->left = node2;
           node3->right = NULL;
           node3->up = node1;
           node3->down = NULL;

/*Return the table's bucket.*/
           return bucket;
           }

/*Find the number of nodes in the table. Skewed if nodes are randomly deleted.*/
int len_table(dlt_node_t *bucket)
{
    dlt_node_t *probe_x, *probe_y;
    int x = 0, y = 0;

for(probe_y; probe_y != NULL; probe_y = probe_y->right) y++;

for(probe_x;probe_x!=NULL;probe_x = probe_x->right) x++;

return x*y;
    }

/*Parse the table, print values.*/
int parse_table(dlt_node_t *bucket){
    dlt_node_t *current, *current_row = bucket;

for ( current_row; current_row!=NULL; current_row = current_row->down ){
        current = current_row;
        for ( current; current != NULL; current = current->right ){
                            printf( "Current value: %i\n", current->value );
                             }
        }
    }
```

Sorry about the copy-paste, nobody on Lockergnome.net had any advice, and they recommended asking here.

Comment: What compiler are you using on Windows? Your use of conio.h suggests an old Borland compiler, but I'm unable to reproduce your crash on Windows with either C++Builder XE or GCC 4.3.3.

Comment: Bloodshed Software Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2.

Comment: BTW: The reason your header files didn't show up was because you formatted the code incorrectly - you're supposed to put 4 spaces before each line of code, rather than wrap it in HTML tags. I've fixed it for you: next time, you can simply paste in your code, select it, and hit the {} button.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why it wasn't showing up. I'm a newbie here, and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function `len_table` you have not initialized your pointers `probe_x` and `probe_y`. (They are not default initialised to NULL in c). So in the first iteration of your loops, your program is likely to crash.

Comment: You are indeed right. I did not notice that. I actually was getting weird results from that function. Thank you very much.